# How to loop recursive data type

Tags: c#, recursive-datastructures

I reading hierarchical data into a recursive data structure.

```
public class Items
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Items> Children { get; set; }
}
```

So its similar to a tree. My problem is, I have no idea how I can loop over all elements or find a inner element with a specific Name. Since it can be very complex/deep I can not really work with nested loops since I don't know how deep it will get.

How can I have a loop over all elements in such a structure?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: You could either try recursion, or keep a `Stack<Items>` of elements to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need solution without recursion, here is one:

```
public Items FindByName(Items root, string targetName)
{
    var stack = new Stack<Items>();
    stack.Push(root);

    Items node;
    while (true)
    {
        node = stack.Pop();
        if (node == null)
        {
            // not found ..
        }
        if (node.Name == targetName)
        {
            break;
        }
        foreach (var child in node.Children)
        {
            stack.Push(child);
        }
    }
    return node;
}
```

Comment: When you are putting items on a stack, why not use the call stack as you would in the recursion. If a stack overflow is not an issue, this solution is not more efficient than recursion.

Comment: You could use a stack, queue or list. The question required an answer without recursion

Comment: I don't know where everyone sees the "no recursion" part in the question. It says "no nested loops" because of unknown depth of the tree. That's a non-issue with recursion.

Comment: I guess "no nested loops" is the slang for recursion here. :) JK

Comment: I don't think so, because a) recursion is slang for recursion and b) recursion doesn't have the issue of not knowing the depth of the tree. What about reading "nested loops" as "nested loops" without further (over-)interpretation?

Answer (score 2):

```
void RecursiveMethod(Items items)
{
    if (items.Children != null)
    {
        foreach (Items i in items.Children)
        {
            RecursiveMethod(i);
        }
    }
    if (items.Name == "YourName")
    {
        // Do your stuff..
    }
}
```

Comment: No he didn't, he said he wanted to avoid nested loops. Recursion is the best method for this structure.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay: define "best", please. :)

Comment: @Dennis: Check the lengths you have to go for an iterative solution. Recursion is defenitely cleaner than that.

Comment: @Sefe: Recursion is obvious. Recursion is natural. Maybe it is simplest. But it is not *the best*.

Comment: @Dennis: Well, that will depend entirely on your requirements. In practically all cases where I had to parse a tree, recursion was the best choice. I don't see a *practical* downside in the majority of the cases.

Comment: @Dennis it is the most logical / easiest to implement / easiest to understand. The "best" solution to traverse a tree structure in 95% of cases.

Comment: Recursion is usually not a good solution for traversing unbalanced trees that can be large, since the degenerate case is a linked list which could cause a `StackOverflowException`. If the tree is guaranteed to be balanced, then a recursive solution is acceptable (and easiest to code).

Answer (score 1):

You need some traversal algorithm implementation.
There are several ones, either recursive, or non-recursive. It depends on your particular use-cases, which one to choose.

E.g., a kind of non-recursive, lazy width traversal:

```
public static class TreeVisitor
{
    public static IEnumerable<TNodeType> WidthTraversal<TNodeType>(TNodeType root, Func<TNodeType, IEnumerable<TNodeType>> getChildNodesFunc)
        where TNodeType : class
    {
        if (root == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(root));
        }

        if (getChildNodesFunc == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(getChildNodesFunc));
        }

        var visited = new HashSet<TNodeType>();
        var queue = new Queue<TNodeType>();

        yield return root;
        visited.Add(root);
        queue.Enqueue(root);

        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            var parent = queue.Dequeue();
            foreach (var child in getChildNodesFunc(parent))
            {
                if (child == default(TNodeType))
                    continue;

                if (!visited.Contains(child))
                {
                    yield return child;
                    visited.Add(child);
                    queue.Enqueue(child);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
        var rootItem = new Items
        {
            Name = "Root",
            Children = new List<Items>
            {
                new Items { Name = "Child1" },
                new Items { Name = "Child2" },
                // etc
            }
        };

        foreach (var item in TreeVisitor.WidthTraversal(rootItem, _ => _.Children))
        {
            // ...
        }
```

Comment: This might just be complicated for a beginner

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Item> items = new List<Item>() { new Item { Name = "Pasta", Children = new List<Item>() { new Item { Name = "Pasta", Children = null } } } };
        List<Item> pastas = GetItemsByName(items, "Pasta");
    }

    private static List<Item> GetItemsByName(List<Item> items, string name)
    {
        List<Item> found = new List<Item>();
        foreach (Item item in items)
        {
            if (item.Name == name)
            {
                found.Add(item);
            }
            if (item.Children != null)
            {
                found.AddRange(GetItemsByName(item.Children, name));
            }
        }
        return found;
    }
}


public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Children { get; set; }
}
```